# Trapezoid Volume and Surface Area

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Given $AB = 6$, $DC = 12$, $CG = 8$. Find the surface area and volume of the object.

I tried solving for h first. By inspection, you can see that the height is equal to the side of the 45°.

Using $h=(6-h)(\tan 60°)$. I got $h=9-3 \sqrt{3}$ then I plug it in to solve the volume.

$$V = \left[\frac12(12+6)(9-3 \sqrt{3)})\right]\times 8$$
$$V = 273.877$$

Then for the surface area, I just added the areas of each faces.

$$SA = 2(9*(9-\sqrt{3}) + 2(8(9-\sqrt{3}) + 18 + 96 $$
$$SA = 298.756$$

I am unsure whether this is correct

Comment: Found! But this is not a homework service. You should post your own attempt and specifically where you're stuck before you get help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried solving it and I got that the height is equal to the side in the 45°. Then, using h=(6-h)(tan 60°). I got h=9-3 sqrt(3) then I plug it in to solve the volume. V=[1/2(12+6)(9-3 sqrt(3))]8=273.877

Comment: I'm not familiar with the surface area of this object. Sorry

Comment: Looks like you're doing fine. For surface area just find all rectangular and trapezoidal areas and sum. You've already worked out the trapezoidal area in your volume calculation. You have the relevant dimensions of two of the four rectangles. For the two "slanted" ones, the widths are the hypotenuses of the two right triangles you already looked at.

Comment: SA= 2(9*(9-sqrt(3)) + 2(8(9-sqrt(3)) + 18 + 96
I got 298.756 for the surface area. I am unsure whether this is correct

Comment: See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is completely correct. Since this is a prism, its volume is simply the area of trapezium $ABCD$ (or $EFGH$) multiplied by $CG$. So the volume is $\frac 12(12+6)(9-3\sqrt 3) \times 8 \approx 273.88$

For the area, just sum the areas of the $4$ rectangles and $2$ (identical) trapeziums.

$ABEF$ has area $8 \times 6 =48$

$DCGH$ area = $8\times 12 = 96$

Trapeziums $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ are congruent, each with area $\frac 12(12+6)(9-3\sqrt 3)$, so total area of these two is $18(9-3\sqrt 3)$

Finally, "slanted" rectangles $BCGF$ and $ADHE$

$BC = \frac h{\sin 60^{\circ}} = 6(\sqrt 3-1)$

Area $BCGF = 8 \times BC = 48(\sqrt 3-1)$

Similarly, $AD = h\sqrt 2 = 9\sqrt 2 - 3\sqrt 6$

Area $ADHE = 8 \times (9\sqrt 2 - 3\sqrt 6) =  72\sqrt 2 - 24\sqrt 6$

Adding it all up, total surface area $\approx 290.64$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* This is a prism with a trapezoidal cross-section. Thus the volume is the area of the cross-section multiplied by the length of the prism. Thus, you only need find the area of the section, and then you'd be done. That's easy since you already know the length of the parallel sides, and you can find the distance between them trigonometrically.